# Google analytics integration in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics-api

```
 try
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                  new ClientSecrets { ClientId = ClientID, ClientSecret = ClientSecret  },
                       new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly, AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsEdit },
                         "user",
                         CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store")).Result;
            return credential;
        }
        catch { return null; }
```

I am using above code for google console web application(Google Analytic) but it gives redirect_uri mismatch error. How i can send redirect_uri.

Answer (score 0):

**redirect_uri** is set up in the [Google Developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/) -> apis & auth -> credentials

Comment: You don't send it its set up in the application from googles side.

Comment: how can integrate Google analytic v3 api with web application

Comment: The code you are using is correct. When you created your application on Googles page and got your clientid and client secrete its there you need to set up the redirect url.

Comment: var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
                AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (result.Credential != null)
            {
                //Code
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect(result.RedirectUri.ToString());
            }
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Analytics.Auth.Store' is denied.

Comment: how can integrate Google analytic v3 api with web application  <-- that's a separate question. note related to this one.

Comment: As stated in the answer you need to go to https://console.developers.google.com/project and set the redirectURI correctly and your code will work.

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'Analytics.Auth.Store' is denied. error

Comment: That's a different error you need to start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Sanaan C ever found an answer ... the reason that your code does not work in a web application is likely because the user that created the Analytics.Auth.Store entry in that user's %APPDATA% folder is NOT the one running your web application.

Does anyone have a solution to this - and please excuse that this question is appended to another ... I actually think this was the intended question in any event ...

===

One simple-minded solution could be to take the credentials created by a user who can respond to the redirect and put it in a folder, with appropriate access permissions, where the user under which the IIS service is being run can find it. Instantiate the FileDataStore with a full path to this folder ...